# How to concatenate Integers and strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search for a substring with the specify pattern using re library. I wrote a function to do that but end up getting this error: Type Error: cannot concatenate str and integers. Below is my function;

```
def searchValue(obs, concept):
try:
    found = re.search('## !!'concept+'=(.+?)!! ##',obs)
except AttributeError:
    found = 'null'
return found

obs= '!!1834=7850!! ## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ## !!1915=Patient is HIV positive since 2016,no presents with pains on the plantar surface and pelvic pain.!! ## !!5096=2013-07-29!! ## !!5219=1068!! ## !!6504=7189!! ## !!6509=6511!! ## !!6575=1107!! ## !!6605=1065!! ## !!7191=MELANOMA OF THE RIGHT HEEL.!! ## !!8723=5622!!'
bett = searchValue(obs, 1915)

print(bett)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: '## !!'concept+'=(.+?)!! ##' is not a correct string.

Comment: For this code you should get *SyntaxError* (missing ***+*** before *concept*).

Comment: As @CristiFati pointed out you are getting that error because you need to do `'## !!'+concept+'=(.+?)!! ##'`.  Python is trying to concat `"str1""str2"` <-- valid python syntax. But in your case `"str2"` is an `int` which is why it errored.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in substrings position I'd use:

```
def searchValue(obs, concept):
    return re.findall('## !!'+ str(concept) + '=(.+?)!! ##',obs)

bett = searchValue(obs, 1915)
print(bett)

>>> ['Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your code:

1. Missing a  ***+*** in `'## !!'concept` (might be a typo?) - yielding syntactically incorrect code (*SyntaxError*)
2. Adding strings (*`'## !!'*) with *int*s (*1915*) - which is not possible (*TypeError*). You have to convert the *int* to *str*

Here's how your pattern (`re.search`'s 1<sup>st</sup> argument) should look like (quickest way, of course there's room for improvements):

> ```py
> >>> concept = 1915
> >>> obs = '!!1834=7850!! ## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ## !!1915=Patient is HIV positive since 2016,no presents with pains on the plantar surface and pelvic pain.!! ## !!5096=2013-07-29!! ## !!5219=1068!! ## !!6504=7189!! ## !!6509=6511!! ## !!6575=1107!! ## !!6605=1065!! ## !!7191=MELANOMA OF THE RIGHT HEEL.!! ## !!8723=5622!!'
> >>>
> >>> found = re.search('## !!' + str(concept) + '=(.+?)!! ##', obs)  # !!! Copy / paste this in your code
> >>>
> >>> found
> <re.Match object; span=(14, 110), match='## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, th>
> >>> found.group()
> '## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ##'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

after some wortk on your code i got something that seems fine; if not let me know.

The important part is to feed the re.search() with a complete string; that's done using .format().

Greetings

```
def searchValue(obs, concept):
    try:
        expression = '## !!{0}=(.+?)!! ##'.format(concept)
        found = re.search(expression, obs)
    except AttributeError:
        found = 'null'
    return found

obs= '!!1834=7850!! ## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ## !!1915=Patient is HIV positive since 2016,no presents with pains on the plantar surface and pelvic pain.!! ## !!5096=2013-07-29!! ## !!5219=1068!! ## !!6504=7189!! ## !!6509=6511!! ## !!6575=1107!! ## !!6605=1065!! ## !!7191=MELANOMA OF THE RIGHT HEEL.!! ## !!8723=5622!!'
bett = searchValue(obs, 1915)

print(bett)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate a string with integer type that's why you are getting the error.
try using this and do share if it solves your problem:

```
bett = searchValue(obs, str(1915))
```

also add the + sign before concept as suggested by @CristiFati

Answer (score 0):

You missed a +. You also need to make the integer that you are trying to concatenate (concept) a string because you cannot concatenate integers with strings. You must also make the 1915 you are searching for in the 'obs' variable a string because 'obs' is a string not an integer.

```
def searchValue(obs, concept):
try:
    found = re.search('## !!' + str(concept) + '=(.+?)!! ##',obs)
except AttributeError:
    found = 'null'
return found

obs= '!!1834=7850!! ## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ## !!1915=Patient is HIV positive since 2016,no presents with pains on the plantar surface and pelvic pain.!! ## !!5096=2013-07-29!! ## !!5219=1068!! ## !!6504=7189!! ## !!6509=6511!! ## !!6575=1107!! ## !!6605=1065!! ## !!7191=MELANOMA OF THE RIGHT HEEL.!! ## !!8723=5622!!'
bett = searchValue(obs, str(1915))

print(bett)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
    found = re.search('## !!' + concept + '=(.+?)!! ##',obs)
```

The correct version is:

```
    found = re.search('## !!' + str(concept) + '=(.+?)!! ##',obs)
```

You have to cast from int to string explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you are missing a + for concat

```
def searchValue(obs, concept):
try:
    found = re.search('## !!'+str(concept)+'=(.+?)!! ##',obs)
except AttributeError:
    found = 'null'
return found

obs= '!!1834=7850!! ## !!1915=Patient is awaiting imaging results, then start darcabazine 250 ml every 21 days.!! ## !!1915=Patient is HIV positive since 2016,no presents with pains on the plantar surface and pelvic pain.!! ## !!5096=2013-07-29!! ## !!5219=1068!! ## !!6504=7189!! ## !!6509=6511!! ## !!6575=1107!! ## !!6605=1065!! ## !!7191=MELANOMA OF THE RIGHT HEEL.!! ## !!8723=5622!!'
bett = searchValue(obs, 1915)

print(bett)
```

Make sure you convert the integer value to string and pass so that it considers it as a string or convert it using str(Integer)